# TeamCity automatic branch merging to newer release branches

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, branching-and-merging

There is a manual how to make an automatic merge in TeamCity:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/automatic-merge.html

There we can select particular branch for merge. But in Bitbucket the automatic merge happens also into higher release branches like:

/feature-* -> /release-1.0 -> /release-2.0 -> /release-2.1 and so on.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver0721/automatic-branch-merging-1115665735.html?utm_campaign=in-app-help&utm_medium=in-app-help&utm_source=stash

does anybody know how to do the same in TeamCity? So the TeamCity automatically recognises the order of releases and automatically merges accordingly.